# Fabrication gem cyclic dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, cyclic-reference, fabrication-gem

I've got a cyclic dependency when worked with `fabrication` gem. Here I'll show you what I've did. Let's suppose I have 2 models:

```
class User < AR::Base
  has_many :messages


class Message < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
```

So, the fabricators for them will be:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  # bla-bla-bla
  messages(count: 5)
end

Fabricator(:message) do
  # bla-bla-bla
  user
end
```

It seems all right, yeah? But when I run `Fabricate(:user)` or `Fabricate(:message)` I get cyclic dependencies, because of fabricating of message fabricates new user, fabricating new user fabricates a messages for him and so on. How can I avoid this diabolic circle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would typically have two `user` fabricators in an instance like this.

```
Fabricator(:user)

Fabricator(:user_with_messages, from: :user) do
  messages(count: 5)
end
```

You could alternatively do this to make what you have work.

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  messages(count: 5) { Fabricate.build(:message, user: nil) }
end
```

The messages will be saved automatically by AR when the user is saved. It will handle setting up the correct references.

Comment: ok, thanks! 2nd method is something new for me. I accept answer, but maybe, someone another offers something better?